# Digital Zoom in matlab (averaging adjacent odd columns and rows)

Tags: matlab, zooming, digital

Im trying to make a zoom without using the [interpolation techniques](http://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=70836), this way i have to:

1. Reduce the size of the image by 2
2. Showing only the odd rows and columns, i reduce the size of the matrix to half (Matrix C)

I have accomplished all this with the following code:

```
A = imread ('image.jpg'); 
    [M, N, L] = size(A);
    C = zeros(M/2, N/2, L);
    j = M;
    for x = 1: 1: M/2
        for y = 1: 1 : N/2
            for z = 1: 1: L
                C(x,y,z) = A(((x*2)-1),((y*2)-1),z);
            end
        end
    end

    C = uint8(C);
    figure
    image(C);
```

However know in order to fill the empty spaces and to do the digital zoom I need to fill all the gaps using the sum of the odd adjacent rows (and columns)

Steps:

1. Original row [1,1][1,2][1,3]
2. After code  [1,1][0,0][1,3]
3. After digital zoom [1,1][([1,1]+[1,3])/2][1,3]

This way i average both sides of the odd rows, next to each other and divide them by 2, by leaving the average sum of the adjacent vectors i shuld be able to do a zoom up, however I have yet to find to do step 3 in my own code  by taking every element (index) of the matrix and not losing them in the process

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that you need to modify the image data but can't lose the original values, then you simply need to create a new temporary variable that is initialized as a copy of the original image. Then compute the new values using the data in the original image but update them in the new temporary variable. Once you are finished the process you can replace the original image with the temporary variable.